# close modal bottom sheet and navigate to another page after clicking the text button

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm displaying **modal bottom sheet** using **`cupertino navigation bar`**, and i want to make the bottom sheet closed when i click the text button to navigate to another page. I use **Navigator.pop(context);** to do it, but it only closing modal bottom sheet and won't go to another page. I'm wondering everyone want to help me solve issue, thank you. [sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPRAS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do By this :

```
  Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(routeName)
```

If you dont have the route specified in main.dart . you can write it like this :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            bodyText1: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
            ),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
            ),
            headline1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
            )),
        canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      //home: MyHomePage(title: ''),
      initialRoute: HomeScreen.homeScreenRoute,
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        'home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the modal closed and the new page pop with the same time. What should i do to make it wait before modal closed first, then pop the new page?